# How to execute aws cli commands with shell_exec?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, shell-exec

Trying to execute aws cli commands with php `shell_exec` on local server (for tests). 
I'm using xampp, 
windows operating system, 
Laravel and php, 
I installed aws cli on windows.

Windows cmd recognizes the aws commands, but when I try to execute the aws command with `shell_exec` i get an error: **"aws is not recognized as an internal or external command"**.

Tried this simple script:

```
$exec = shell_exec('aws --version');

$exec return null.
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: It probably isn't found in the path. Try referencing `aws` via the full path.

Answer (score 1):

if you can't run the command directly in shell_exec(), then what you can do is make a batch file with the command and place it on the root of your website. Then, just run:

```
<?php echo exec("script.bat"); ?>
```

also, make sure to put any environment variables needed and recommend to use full path for the aws executable

Comment: I created this bat file:
cmd /k "aws --version"

when I run it on windows cmd it returns the expected response. But then I run it with exec function like this:

$ecec= exec('C:\awsbat\first_simple_batch.bat');

$exec returns the php local path:
"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\php_project\\public>"

How can I display the output?

Comment: can you replace aws with the full path of the aws command as I mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It was pretty simple. It doesn't enough to restart xampp. I also had to quit xampp and re enter